# Port forwarding on NAT using KVM/QEMU

Tags: ssh, qemu, nat, kvm

I'm using NAT mode for guest networking. I need my machines to be accessible from outside the guest. I've set up iptables to port forward a specific port on host to port 22 on guest, but this does not seem to work.

I added this rules:

```
# Port Forwardings
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9867 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.136:22

# Forward traffic through eth0 - Change to match you out-interface
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

When I `ssh 192.168.122.136` from host it works perfectly, however when I try `ssh 192.168.122.136 -p 9867` it shows `ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.1 port 9867: Connection refused`

I've enabled port forwarding on `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`

using `iptables -t nat -L` shows that the rule is set up on iptable

```
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9867 to:192.168.122.136:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113521/iptables-redirect-local-request-with-nat/113651#113651). basicly I changed the above to

```
# connections from outside
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9867 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.136:22
# for local connection
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9867 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.136:22

# Masquerade local subnet
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
```